# How can I make form element in one line (css)?

Tags: html, css

I want to make this search `form` element in one line...

[image]

And code,

```html
<form id="search" class="navbar-form search" role="search" style="width:40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" method="GET">
  <select name="search_target">
    <option value="title">제목</option>
    <option value="content">내용</option>
    <option value="title_content">제목+내용</option>
    <option value="username">아이디</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="search_keyword" placeholder="Type to search">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit icon-search"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: What issue you are getting into this ?

Comment: What is your current CSS? As on large screen sizes this is one line.

Answer (score 0):

it's wrapping the elements because the area is too small to fit all of them.

you can add this css, no html changes needed and the wrapping will stop!

```
#search{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```